# XPages file upload on iPad - compress images

Tags: jquery, xpages

I have a mobile web application built in XPages and using jQuery Mobile for the UI, accessed via Safari on an iPad. The user can upload images from the iPad camera via a normal XPages file upload control.

The customer has asked whether it is possible to compress the images before they are uploaded to the Domino server due to the time this is taking over 3G.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the image as a way of reducing its size. Otherwise you will need to look at plugins that zip the files.